# Как можно получить запросы IOS приложения в веб?

Tags: windows, ios, http

Можно ли как-то получить запросы, которые приложение на iOS отправляет/получает и на какие сайты оно это делает? Была идея использовать снифер на Windows, может посоветуете какой-то? Или возможно существуют другие способы

Answer (score 0):

Пользуюсь вот этим - https://www.charlesproxy.com/
Советую. Позволяет не просто сниффить трафик, но и дебажить обращения к бэкэнду.